# Future<List<Object>> function() {} doesn't show code suggestions for Flutter (Android Studio)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hint, completion

I have recently made a simple Todo App and had a strange problem with code completion in Flutter. The code suggestion works well until I type **Future<List>...** and since then it doesn't work anymore.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So I had tried the following

- Invalidated caches and restarted
- Re-downloaded Flutter plugin

but the problem was still there. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the Error?, please post the Error here

Comment: Actually, the error is that there is no code suggestion

Comment: It must be your IDE (Android Studio). That happens all the time. But from the look of your code, I cannot see Todo Class

Comment: Yeah, The Todo Class is very simple, you can see my editable post

Comment: Yeah, Restart Android Studio, I use android studio, mine does that too sometimes

Comment: I tried but the matter doesn't have any change

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the SDK version will do just fine. Hope it will help you.